# Why is cherry picking trying to apply past commits?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have never cherry pick before. To experiment I did
I have a master branch where a file has some contents.
Over there there are commits "3" and commits "4" (fictional numbers, in reality they are commit ids) where each one adds one line to the file

commit "3" adds "this is commit 3"
commit "4" adds "this is commit 4"

I went back to master and did

```
git cherry-pick 4
```

and I expected to easily add "this is commit 4" to the file
but instead I got a conflict where there are two options (none of them the desired behavior)

```
Auto-merging onemoredoc.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in onemoredoc.txt
error: could not apply 4... add line with 4
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

current change : nothing

incoming change: both line "this is commit 3" and "this is commit 4"

Why? and how can I just add "this is commit 4" to the master

Comment: The changes of Commit 4 are dependent on Commit 3. The line "this is commit 4" expects there is a line "this is commit 3" and then gets appended to it. However, the commit 3 line is missing. It leads to merge conflict. There are some merge strategies that help to automatically resolve the conflict, but there is no common solution to all cases.

Comment: But that is counterintuitive. If I had to apply everything I might as well merge (which I dont want). Is there a way to only "cherry pick" only the lines I want?

Comment: It does not require you to apply everything. It's just a conflict when applying the line you want. When you manually add the line, you still have to find the proper place (the context) first before you write down the line. Imagine how you decide where the proper place is if you manually modify the file.

Comment: If you view commits as instructions how to modify files, then the instruction of commit 4 is not just "Add the line 'this is commit 4'", but it rather is "Add the line 'this is commit 4' after the line 'this is commit 3'". Now, how do you follow the latter instruction if there is no line 'this is commit 3' in the file? Sure, you ask back what to do. In Git terms, this is called a merge conflict.

Comment: @j6t Ok, but then why the options are all or nothing. Line3 +line 4 or nothing. This is a pet project but I am planning to use this in a larger project where there are several files and many more lines added

Comment: You misunderstand what you see. The "options" that you see are not what you *have* to choose from. In fact, choosing one or the other is actually *wrong* in the majority of conflicts (it's a typical beginner's error). Since Git could not find out what to do with the change, but you know that you actually only want to add the line 'this is commit 4', that is what you will do now manually. You can achieve it in several ways. One is to choose the incoming change (both lines), and then remove the line 'this is commit 3'. The leaves you with the desired result.

Comment: I want to clarify the comment from above. Git is not telling you to chose one or another, git is telling you what the file looks like in the 2 different versions of the file you are merging/combining but you yourself need to figure out what the resulting file should look like.

Comment: And the type of tool you absolutely want to use to help `figure out what the resulting file should look like` is a proper 3-way merge tool. I recommend [using KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3),